# Are mantissas of irrationals provably unique, at a given precision?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Many thanks to all responders!

Is there any research as to the uniqueness of mantissas of irrationals? It's easy to see that the mantissa of the square root of 5 (0.236067977...) and the mantissa of square root of 3 (0.732050808...) are not the same. But what of the mantissa of the square root of the prime: 46501977969271565023037204587654566480956407319755226591068050362266699497671579410830361849348542725792242523 being the same as the mantissa of the square root of 30745442551887? (they're not) But, has anyone researched this? Is there a math proof that shows that all mantissas of irrationals are unique? (Of course, as they are irrationals (infinite non-repeating) - this seems, intuitively, true.) However, if the mantissa is approximated at, say, 500 digits, could there be collisions? Thank you for any research you can point me to!

Answer (score 2):

I take it by "mantissa", you mean the digits after the decimal point, and that mantissa you gave for the square root of 2 was meant to be for the square root of 5.

Here are some basic observations:

1. If you cut off at 500 digits, there's only $10^{500}$ many possibilities. Test $10^{500} + 1$ many numbers, and you'll have to find a collision.
2. As for exact matches with no cutoff, to say that $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{B}$ have the same mantissa is to say that $\sqrt{A} = N + \sqrt{B}$ for some whole number $N$. It follows that $A = \sqrt{A}^2 = \left(N + \sqrt{B}\right)^2 = N^2 + B + 2N\sqrt{B}$, and thus $\sqrt{B} = \frac{A - N^2 - B}{2N}$. If we take $A$ and $B$ to be whole numbers as well, this shows that $\sqrt{B}$ is rational.

   However, by the rational root theorem (or put another way, by the fact that squaring the numerator and denominator of a fraction in lowest terms gives a fraction still in lowest terms), the only rational square roots of whole numbers are themselves whole numbers.

   Thus, the only case where $\sqrt{A}$ and $\sqrt{B}$ have the same mantissas for distinct whole numbers $A$ and $B$ is when $A$ and $B$ are square numbers (so the mantissa is just 0.000...).

Comment: Sridhar, you are awesome! Thank you. This is very well presented and completely understandable. You're the best! (And thanks for the correction on the typo)

Comment: Re point 2: isn't having the same mantissas implies the number differ, multiplicatively, by a power of 10?

Comment: @Ofir, the mantissa is the part after the decimal point, so having the same mantissa implies (and is implied by) the numbers differing additively by an integer. Unless you're thinking of the mantissa of the common logarithm rather than the mantissa of the number itself.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh I see, my bad. Thanks.